# opencart htaccess force ssl getting error redirect loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, opencart

im already set my opencart config to using SSL, 
then i want redirect when user not use https in address to force use https

im browsing an got this tutorial
http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/ssl/how-to-force-ssl-using-the-htaccess-file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

but i got the error in chrome
this webpage has a redirect loop

Comment: Does turning on https in opencart perform a redirect? You might have conflicting rules with PHP and .htaccess.

Comment: @PanamaJack i dont know, im newbie in opencart.
so the htaccess fine?